# Trying to call lib.exe from Visual Studio Command Prompt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to call lib.exe from the Visual Studio Command Prompt so I can build the .lib file from my .def file. When I run this:

lib.exe /MACHINE:X86 /DEF:MyDLL.def

In the end I want to export my functions to be used when I call them from within a DLL. I am having to create this library because I have 2 DLLs and the first one calls the second one. The second one I just have the DLL itself and do not have the header or the .cpp file. I do not have the .lib file hence why I am trying to create one. I have used this tool [expdef - def file generator](http://purefractalsolutions.com/show.php?a=utils/expdef) to create my .def file and following this tutroial: [How To Create 32-bit Import Libraries Without .OBJs or Source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131313), so I could build the library file.

The error I receive from the command prompt is:

***LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MyDLL.def'***

So I have tried searching through many forums and searches but cannot find a solution to why I see this.

I have posted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18004602/how-to-call-a-c-dll-method-inside-a-c-dll) on another forum here where it explains what I totally want to do.

Comment: The likely cause is an exported function that's forwarded to wpdes32.dll.  So you'll have to do that one first.  Using DLLs that you cannot get support for is somewhere between illegal and very unpractical.

Comment: @HansPassant, Sorry the .def was MyDLL.def in the error: LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MyDLL.def'

Comment: Obfuscating these names doesn't help us help you.  Sure sounds like you are doing something illegal.

Comment: @HansPassant Sorry it seems so devious to you, but I should not give out the names of my companies proprietery DLLs. I am going to get the header and .cpp file from them soon, I just was told that R&D may not want to give them to me. Hence I am in this "unpractical" situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option if you don't have and export .lib for a DLL is to the Win32 APIS LoadLibrary() and GetProcAddress().  Call these APIs from the caller code, using the names of the exported entry points of the callee DLL.  You don't need to mention the callee DLL at all when linking the first DLL.

To get the names of the exported entry points, you can use a tool like "dumpbin /exports" or depends.exe on the callee DLL.

Of course, you have to know the signatures and any other assumptions of the called entry points, or you will get undefined behavior.  If worst comes to worst, you may be able to deduce these by debugging the call.

Comment: This seems to be the route I will go. I have been able to use the LoadLibrary() function to add the DLL. I also used the GetProcAddress() to find my entry method names and while debugging I have confirmed the EntryPoint address is the same as the GetProcAddress() (using Dependency Walker) so this is great. However I am now having buffer overrun errors so that is on my side and I need to find why. Your suggestion however was suitable for my question and I now need to post a new question for a new problem. Thank you tremendously for your answer.